# register and unregister angular js watch

Tags: angularjs, watch

In my application I want to provide a checkbox for users to toggle whether the app periodically polls for new data in the background. 
I have setup a watch to do the data polling. And i know that if i assign a variable to that watch when created I can call that variable and the watch will be disabled/unregistered.
My issue is that when the users clicks the textbox to on i want the watch to come back to life. I have not found the best way to get that done.
Here is my sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vbahole22/Gdfyc/) which somewhat illustrates the issue. I think if i could get it to work there i can rig up the rest of it.
The part that is not working is the part where the watch needs to come back on line:

```
 if ($scope.counter === 15) {
        $scope.$watch('counter', theWatchFunction);
        $scope.test = "back on";
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot simply unregister an watcher and wait for it to automatically re-register again. The moment you run `myWatch()` everything inside the `theWatchFunction` will never run again. You can register a new watcher but **not inside** the `theWatchFunction`.

You can, for example, re-register the `counter` watcher on the `time` watcher: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/Lw3Lp/

Answer (score 0):

You were close, the reason your jsfiddle is not working is because at counter 7, you cancel the watch.  Since your code to turn the watch back on was in theWatchFunction, it is never called, since the watch has been disabled thus that function is no longer being executed.

I've put the check for the counter to turn back on the watch in your timeout function and it seem to be working correctly.

```
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.time = new Date();
        $scope.counter++;
        if ($scope.counter === 15) {
           myWatch = $scope.$watch('counter', theWatchFunction);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

I've forked a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bWfP/) demonstrating a working version that should get you on your way. Hope that helps!